# Image serving with StreamedContent fails in @ViewScoped but works in @SessionScoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, graphicimage

Ok, What am I doing wrong? I try to create simple image uploader with image preview. I have a product in my database with some name, description, etc. And image. My goal is to create edit (and later add) form for manager user. I created a bean:

```
package pl.jedenpies.sklep.beans;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;

import pl.jedenpies.sklep.dto.Image;
import pl.jedenpies.sklep.utils.ImageUtil;

@ViewScoped @ManagedBean(name = "editProductForm")
public class NewEditProductForm {

    private Image currentThumbnail;
    private Image uploadedImage;
    private Image uploadedThumbnail;

    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Saved");
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(event.getFile().getInputstream());
        BufferedImage thumbnail = ImageUtil.makeThumbnail(originalImage);
        setUploadedImage(originalImage);
        setUploadedThumbnail(thumbnail);
    }


    public Image getCurrentThumbnail() {
        return currentThumbnail;
    }
    public void setCurrentThumbnail(BufferedImage currentThumbnail) {
        this.currentThumbnail = new Image(currentThumbnail);
    }
    public Image getUploadedImage() {
        return uploadedImage;
    }
    public void setUploadedImage(BufferedImage uploadedImage) {
        this.uploadedImage = new Image(uploadedImage);
    }
    public Image getUploadedThumbnail() {
        return uploadedThumbnail;
    }
    public void setUploadedThumbnail(BufferedImage uploadedThumbnail) {
        this.uploadedThumbnail = new Image(uploadedThumbnail);
    }
}
```

where Image is a class wrapping BufferedImage and allowing to create StreamedContent object:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;

public class Image {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Image() {}

    public Image(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public DefaultStreamedContent stream() throws IOException { 

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }    

    if (image == null) return null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(bais, "image/png");
    }
}
```

My xhtml page is:

```
<h:form id="editProductForm">
  <div class="form" style="width: 830px;">

    <p:panel id="imageUploader">
      <c:if test="#{editProductForm.currentThumbnail != null}">
        <p:graphicImage
          styleClass="thumbnail"
          id="currentThumbnail" value="#{editProductForm.currentThumbnail.stream()}" cache="false" />                
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="#{editProductForm.currentThumbnail == null}">
        <p:graphicImage 
          value="/resources/images/logo-plaskie-duze.png"
          styleClass="thumbnail" />
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="#{editProductForm.uploadedThumbnail != null}">
        <p:graphicImage
          styleClass="thumbnail"
          id="uploadedThumbnail" value="#{editProductForm.uploadedThumbnail.stream()}" cache="false" />
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="#{editProductForm.uploadedThumbnail == null}">
        <p:graphicImage
          styleClass="thumbnail empty"
          id="uploadedThumbnail" />
      </c:if>    
      <p:fileUpload 
        style="border: 1px solid green;"
        fileUploadListener="#{editProductForm.handleFileUpload}"        
        auto="true"
        update=":editProductForm:imageUploader"
        mode="advanced"
        dragDropSupport="true"

        sizeLimit="20000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
      </p:fileUpload>
    </p:panel>
  </div>
  </h:form>
```

When I try to use my new form, freshly uploaded image is not displaying. When I change the scope to @SessionScoped, it works. But I'm not interested in making this bean session scoped. Is it even going to work with view scope? Or maybe I just need to keep image in session this way or another?

As @BalusC suggested I tried "special getter method approach" (I tried it before too), but without a result. When I set the scope to View, method `stream()` is called once in `PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE` and I get `22:10:22,816 SEVERE [org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler] (default task-58) Error in streaming dynamic resource. null` in my logs.

Comment: @BalusC: OK, I tried the "special getter" approach. Without a result.

Comment: Then you didn't exactly follow that approach. That answer also explains why storing them in the view scope doesn't work. Just store them somewhere (DB, FS, etc) and pass its unique identifier as `<f:param>` to an application scoped bean as shown in the proper approach.